# How to add lines to the object like the image shown

Tags: modeling, lines

Does anyone know how to add lines to my object like this image?
[image: The image with the lines I'm trying to replicate]

My object I'm trying to add lines to:
[image: my object I'm trying to add lines to]

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 0):

You can create curves, array them and place on them on the object like this:[image]

Then use boolean modifier on the bag selecting the curves as boolean object. Then apply and you got this:
[image]

If it doesn't create booleans after applying try switching from exact to fast in boolean settings. For curves to follow the surface of the object you can either manually bend them or play with shrinkwrap modifier first.

Answer (score 0):

Try a shader like this. The "ridges" are created by a wave texture. I used a Noise texture before the Vector Math (Add) going into the Wave texture to make the ridges not perfectly straight (combined with the small amount of distortion on the Wave texture Node itself.) The Magic texture is used just to give that "machine embroidered pattern". This used as simply a bump map goes a long way:

[image: Purse]

If you want to go one farther, you can use true displacement as well (Cycles only). Make sure you have a heavily subdivided model, and connect like this. You can also manipulate the Magic Texture with some ColorRamps to make that "glittery" look by connecting them to the metallic and roughness inputs:

[image: Displace]